# How to access methods "across" a hierarchy of JButtons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have two types of buttons extending `JButton` and I need one button to access a get method from the other. but because because the `isPressed()` method is not a part of button I can not call it.

Clarification: I have a type of button. When I press that button a boolean is set to true. I want another button to access that boolean.

```
public class EmptySpace extends JButton {

  protected int x; 
  protected int y;
  protected String name;

  public EmptySpace(String text, int x, int y){
    super(text);
    this.name = text;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
      @Override
      public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
      Board.toStringText.setText(e.getSource().toString());
      }
    });

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
          @Override
          public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
          if(Board.buildButton.getIsPressed()){ //ERROR HERE

          }
          }
        });
  }

  public String toString(){
      return "Name: " + name + " Xcoords: " + x + " Ycoords: " + y;

  }


public class BuildButton extends JButton {

boolean isPressed = false;

public BuildButton(){

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
          @Override
          public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
          isPressed = true;
          Board.BuildIsPressed.setText( "Building : "+ boardRunner.numberOfbiulds +" builds left.");
          }
        });

}
public boolean getIsPressed(){
    return isPressed;
}
```

Comment: 1) Don't use MouseListeners with JButtons. 2) Please clarify your problem a lot. Explain the details as if we don't know what you're trying to do or what your code not shown looks like.

Comment: I used mouse listener for MouseEntered()

Comment: That's not a valid reason. You should add a ChangeListener on the JButton's ButtonModel and check for `isRollover()` to be true. If you use a MouseListener and listen for press, then the button will be active even when it is set to be disabled. But more importantly and again, please explain your problem better.

Comment: Whats the problem with MouseListeners though?

Comment: See above -- you have a disconnect between the state of the button and its responsiveness, something that is very dangerous. But **again** please explain your problem in greater detail.

Comment: *"When I press that button a boolean is set to true"*  Use a `JCheckBox` or  `JToggleButton`.  In 15 years of Java development, I have *never* found a need to extend `JButton`!

Comment: I agree with @AndrewThompson that there is no reason in the code above or explanation for extending JButton, especially when no innate JButton behaviors are being overridden.

Comment: Question: how can the two different class objects be pressed at the same time? Or should one be a JToggleButton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is to separate your model out from your GUI, to add an ActionListener to one button and in that listener, set a boolean in your program's model. Then the ActionListener from the other button can access that state when and if needed.

Other side recommendations:

- Avoid over-use of inheritance, and in general favor composition.
- Avoid using MouseListeners with JButtons since this alters JButtons so that they do not behave as expected -- space bar will stop working on a focused JButton, the JButton's actions will still occur even when disabled.